# How to visualize and represent many (>20) post-hoc hypothesis tests and p-values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-visualization, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I have a repeated measure design with 2 factors, one of which has 3 levels and the other has 4 levels.

This results in 66 pairwise comparisons when I use `lsmeans()`

The model looks like this:

```r
model <- lme(freq ~ Intensity*Frequency, random=~1|Subject, 
             data=filter(summary_by_subject, Genotype=="WT"))
```

And the post hoc looks like this:

```r
lsmeans(model, list(pairwise~Intensity*Frequency), 
     adjust="Tukey")
```

And it outputs many comparisons.

How does one represent these comparisons well? Only show the significant p-values with a * or line? Or a table? In other words, what's a good way to report and represent these comparisons?

Comment: Maybe you should apply p-value adjustment for multiplicity.

Comment: Since these are pairwise, a correlation matrix type might be useful. Some kind of heatmap is a possibility. You could use one half to communicate mean differences, other half to communicate mean difference divided by standard error, so a $z$-score of sorts. If there's a pattern that appears, then the heatmap option might be nice. Alternatively, it could be information overload.

Comment: There is a `cld()` function that produces a compact-letter display of the comparisons. Regarding @michaelchernick, note that there is a Tukey adjustment already. Consider switching to the emmeans package, as lsmeans will be deprecated some months from now.

Comment: You might also consider doing only the simple comparisons (comparing one factor’s levels holding the other fixed): `emm = emmeans(model, ~ Intensity * Frequency)` and then `pairs(emm, simple = “each”)`

Comment: It would probably help you get better answers if you could post a small example (possibly fake) dataset for people to work with.

Comment: Thanks all. This is a more general question. My specific data are not really needed here. I'm asking more for best practices on representing many pairwise comparisons. Putting a bunch of starts and lines doesn't seem well-suited.